# How to cut a string given some parameters

Tags: java, string

```
public int cut(int b){
    String str1;
    b = 0;
    Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Write your string: ");
    str1 = str.next();
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Write a number: ");
    int num1 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Write another number: ");
    int num2 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(str1.substring(num1, num2));
    return b;
}
```

This is my code so far. I want for a user to write a string and write from where to where he wants to cut the string he just entered. The part I can't get is getting that substring.

Comment: And which is the problem that you are facing (why does this not work as you expected)?

Comment: in the last part when i try ti print the substring it wont appear

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Place your `return b` inside the brackets and try again.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having *spaces* in your string. Use `Scanner#nextLine()` instead.

For an input, "my input string"

```
str1 = str.next(); // returns "my" only
```

because *space* is Scanner's default delimiter. To read the whole line use

```
str1 = str.nextLine(); // returns "my input string"
```

Secondly, you're not using `Scanner str` to read the numbers at all. It should be

```
int num1 = str.nextInt(); // instead of in.nextInt()
```

You should also check that the numbers are within bounds or, I think better catch `IndexOutOfBoundsException` itself. Would take care of negatives and what not.

```
try {
    System.out.println(str1.substring(num1, num2));
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("Range specified is out of bounds for '" + str1 + "'");
}
```

Comment: Might as well add a check that the combined size of `num1` and `num2` isn't exceeding the length!

Comment: my code is validated its just that its in spanish so i didnt write it all but the System.out.println wont show me the substring

Comment: You're not using scanner to read the numbers at all. It should be `str.nextInt()`.